# TypeError: img data type = 17 is not supported

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I create red image and try to save it via cv2.imwrite

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2

    RED = [0, 0, 255]
    IMAGE_SIZE = 100

    image = np.empty([IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE], dtype=type(RED))
    for i in range(IMAGE_SIZE):
        for j in range(IMAGE_SIZE):
           image[i, j] = RED

    cv2.imwrite("red.png", image)
```

But I get error

```
     File "C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/Programms/image-processing-cource/Tracks.py", line 11, in save_image
cv2.imwrite(name, image)
    TypeError: img data type = 17 is not supported
```

How to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you use `dtype=type(RED)` for `image`?  `type(RED)` is a python list; using that makes `image` an array of python objects (and not an with a numeric type).  Why not use, say, `dtype=int`?

Comment: If I use `dtype=type(int)` (and `RED = 200`) then I will get the same error

Comment: Ue `dtype=int` (not `type(int)`).  Setting the `dtype` sets the data type of the elements of the array that you are creating.

Comment: Also, if you are trying to create an array that holds RGB components, the shape should be `(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3)`.  E.g `image = np.empty([IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3], dtype=int)`.   If you want the elements to be, say, 8 bit unsigned integers (a typical size for images), you would use `dtype=np.uint8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dtype = type(RED)` gives you type `list` and not type `int`.

you need:

```
image = np.empty([IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3], dtype=type(RED[0]))
```